# On iPhone 5 & 6 there appears an empty line on the right, have you seen anything like that?

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a site and I use bootstrap. This problem comes up on iphone5 & 6. There is an empty line on the right of the page (it is dark beacuse of the backgroud color). Check out the picture!

I realized that if I set the width to 103% or 105% or something more than 100% it goes okay. I am not sure if bootstrac causes the problem but it can be.

(I use all the meta tags, and everything is set to 100%)

Have you seen anything like this before? Could you please help me what can cause the problem? Or how to fix this?

[image: bug]

Comment: Try to debug it. Connect your iPhone to a Mac (using USB cable), start Safari and select the device from the *Debug* menu. If you haven't used web inspector in Safari yet, you might need to enable the *Debug* menu first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Their is `background-color:#000` added in your css. remove it or use `background-color:#ffffff`
   [image]
2. Id footflex img is having too much margin causing it overflow on the right, try reducing it.
   [image]
   Its not just on iphone's may be its on more devices too.

Comment: Thanks very much!!! I rather set the flex to wrap... :) But thanks! I checked through all the site but I found nothing... I missed the bottom part... :)